# Change color of a line segment from a new point layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling, expression, qfield

i have a shp with an infrastructure and I was wondering if I can change the color of its segments after doing a snap  of a point from a new layer on a
the line vertex. The infrastructure has start and end point and its coordinate in the attributes and I would like to use a point to change the color from vertex A to B (green if the infrastructure segment Is correct or red if its not correct) and show the message in the label.

At the Moment I can do this but with a new line layer but I would like to know If I can do this with points.

This is what I want to do with a new point layer over a vertex.
[image]

Is there any way to make the new points read the START and END attributes of the segments and do automatic coloring?

I want to set up the project in QGIS and use it in the same way with QFIELD

Comment: Can you please provide an example (sketch)? Rather complex interactions like this one may seem obvious to you who "invented" them, but descriptions often fall short of transmitting the whole idea correctly.

Comment: yeah you are right. Sorry but I wrote the question with my smartphone. Now I'm adding a screenshot up here

Comment: I don't see any points in the image. Can you clarify?

Comment: I didn't actually insert any points because I don't know how to get the desired result. I uploaded the image where I performed the method I want but with lines. In this case I passed the lines of a new layer all over the vertices of the segments that took the colors green and red. My goal is to insert a point above a vertex and that it can read the X_ET and Y_ET fields  of the infrastructure layer and then color the segment by itself but I don't know how to do it and if it is possible of course

Comment: So you want to colour a point based on an attribute of a different layer?

Comment: I want the point that colors the infrastructure layer segment from vertex A to vertex B after reading the start and end coordinate attributes always from the infrastructure layer. I need the point as a base for labels that I need to place near the segment (and to color the lines too)

Comment: Why don't you place your label by data defined override using `start_point`?

Comment: How is this procedure done?